# AWS Can't create Elastic beanstalk Node.js Worker using awscli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I want to create a elastic beanstalk worker tier instance using aws CLI commands and I am getting below error.

```
[Instance: i-d848c050] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: missing required parameter params[:table_name] - (ArgumentError). Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/sqsd/hooks/firstboot/02-start-sqsd.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

And In /var/log/eb-activity.log

```
init: missing required parameter params[:table_name] (ArgumentError)
at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.23/lib/aws-sdk-core/param_validator.rb:26:in `validate!'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.23/lib/aws-sdk-core/param_validator.rb:11:in `validate!'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.23/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_validator.rb:20:in `call'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.23/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:14:in `call'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.23/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/dynamodb_simple_attributes.rb:112:in `call'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.23/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:21:in `call'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.23/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:21:in `call'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.23/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.23/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:207:in `block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/storage_manager.rb:81:in `update_registration'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/storage_manager.rb:19:in `verify_table'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election/daemon.rb:37:in `initialize'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election.rb:8:in `new'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/vendor/AWSMACLE/lib/leader_election.rb:8:in `create'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/lib/aws-sqsd/cron.rb:241:in `leader_election_daemon'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/lib/aws-sqsd/cron.rb:30:in `initialize'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/lib/aws-sqsd/daemon.rb:44:in `new'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/lib/aws-sqsd/daemon.rb:44:in `initialize'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/bin/aws-sqsd:34:in `new'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/bin/aws-sqsd:34:in `start'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/bin/aws-sqsd:83:in `launch'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sqsd-2.0/bin/aws-sqsd:111:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd:23:in `load'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd:23:in `<main>'
```

Below are my commands which I am running in powershell script file.

```
#Cretae an application
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application --application-name sample-ebs-app

aws elasticbeanstalk check-dns-availability --cname-prefix sample-ebs-cname

aws elasticbeanstalk describe-application-versions --application-name sample-ebs-app --version-label v1

aws elasticbeanstalk create-configuration-template --application-name sample-ebs-app --template-name v1 --solution-stack-name  "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.6 running Node.js"

aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment --application-name sample-ebs-app --template-name v1 --environment-name sample-ebs-env --tier file://ebs-tier.json --option-settings file://ebs-options.json
```

Below is the ebs-tier.json

```
{
"Version": " ",
"Type": "SQS/HTTP",
"Name": "Worker"
}
```

And ebs-options.json

```
[
 {
    "OptionName": "Availability Zones", 
    "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg", 
    "Value": "any"
}, 
{
    "OptionName": "Cooldown", 
    "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg", 
    "Value": "360"
}, 
{
    "OptionName": "MaxSize", 
    "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg", 
    "Value": "10"
}, 
{
    "OptionName": "MinSize", 
    "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg", 
    "Value": "1"
}, 
{
    "OptionName": "BlockDeviceMappings", 
    "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
}, 
{
    "OptionName": "EC2KeyName", 
    "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration", 
    "Value": ""
}, 
{
    "OptionName": "IamInstanceProfile", 
    "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration", 
    "Value": "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
}, 
{
    "OptionName": "InstanceType", 
    "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration", 
    "Value": "t1.micro"
}, 
{
    "OptionName": "EnvironmentType", 
    "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment", 
    "Value": "LoadBalanced"
}]
```

Comment: EBS = elastic block store.

Comment: EBS = Elastic Beanstalk

Comment: @MarkB Do you have any idea why it is failing?

Comment: No, I'm trying to tell you that your question is difficult to read because you are making up your own abbreviation for Elastic Beanstalk when AWS already has another service that is called EBS.

Comment: Are you using the correct IAM permissions for this Worker Tier? Be sure the role that you are trying to use has these permissions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.roles.aeb.html#AWSHowTo.iam.policies.actions.worker